# Open button with different data-attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a table with 3 buttonsand I am using `jquery-"3.2.1"`.

I am trying to use the below javascript-file `Builder` to load the proper data later in the if statements.

My `expected output` is:

If pressing f.ex.: the `Add CPU` button, then the alert message `console.log("cpu clicked")` should appear.

Below you can find my minimum viable example:

```js
class Builder {
  constructor() {
    this.events();
  } // end constructor

  events() {
    $(".btn btn-primary btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this));
  }

  // methods
  ourClickDispatcher(e) {
    var currentButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn btn-primary btn-sm");
    console.log("test")

    if (currentButton.data('exists') == 'cpu') {
      console.log("cpu clicked")
    }

    if (currentButton.data('exists') == 'motherboard') {
      console.log("motherboard clicked")
    }

    if (currentButton.data('exists') == 'graphic-card') {
      console.log("graphic-card clicked")
    }
  }

}

export default Builder;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CPU</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-cpu="cpu" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                            Add CPU
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Motherboard</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-motherboard="motherboard" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                            Add Motherboard
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Graphic Card</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-graphicCard="graphic-card" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                            Add Graphic Card
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see all 3 buttons have the same `class` attribute, but differentiate in the `data-` attribute to load the proper output.

Any suggestions why the below script does not give me the `expected output` if any of the buttons is clicked?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with `$(".btn btn-primary btn-sm")` you want to target the element with all these classes then you need to use

```
$(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm")
```

(*no spaces and a `.` for each class, that is is the correct css syntax*)

Secondly, your data attributes (*according to your script*) should all be named `data-exists` with a different value, and not a differently named attribute for each.

so

```
<button type="button" data-exists="cpu"  ...> 
<button type="button" data-exists="motherboard"  ...>
<button type="button" data-exists="graphic-card"  ...>
```

---

if you indeed wanted to check for the existance of that attribute you should use

```
if (currentButton[0].dataset.cpu) {...}
if (currentButton[0].dataset.motherboard) {...}
if (currentButton[0].dataset.graphicCard) {...}
```

or if  you have to use jQuery (*browsers not supporting dataset*) use the `.is` method

```
if (currentButton.is('[data-cpu]')) {...}
// etc
```